# i am sending request from angluarjs to Codeigniter (mobile to php server) but the response had HTTP status code 404

Tags: angularjs, json, codeigniter

```
    angular.module('Login').controller('loginControler',  function 
($scope,$http,$window) {
$scope.login = function () {
$scope.isRequestSent=true;
$scope.reponseErrorMessage = false;
var request = $http({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost/restserver/user",
headers: {"Accept":"applocation/json","Authorization":"wq1okCGyet62UyikMpbt"},
contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8;",
dataType: 'json',
});
/* Successful HTTP post request or not */
request.success(function (response){
alert(response);
});
request.error(function (response){
alert(response);
$scope.isRequestSent=false;
});
}
});


<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User extends CI_controller {
private $loginRequestdata;
public function __construct()
{   
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");
    parent::__construct();

}
}
?>
```

the things is i made small hybrid mobile application by using angularjs and i developed service for giving response for mobile request while i  am sending request from mobile to server i'm getting error please any on can help me to resolve this issue.

[This my error screenshot what i got from server when i called api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hpnD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot and code, the first console error message `OPTIONS http://localhost/restserver/user 404 (Not Found)` indicates that the `OPTIONS` method resolves in a 404. Meaning `http://localhost/restserver/user` is unreachable.

Try changing your API call URL to `http://localhost:8000/restserver/user` instead of `http://localhost/restserver/user`

As in the code above, change the `$http` request with correct API endpoint URL.

```
var request = $http({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/restserver/user",
  headers: {"Accept":"applocation/json","Authorization":"wq1okCGyet62UyikMpbt"},
  contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8;",
  dataType: 'json',
});
```

Comment: Still i am getting this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/codeIgniter. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"

Comment: What result do you get when direct access to a API method? As example the `http://localhost:8000/restserver/user` through Postman?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS in your server, which you've already done by adding response headers. Now just add a `die()` method if your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is `"OPTIONS"`

**Example:**

```
public function __construct()
    {

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
            die();
        }

        parent::__construct();

    }
```